# How to get the name and values from xml array using php

Tags: php, xml

Here is my Xml code:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
 [resultsRows] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [row] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [dimension] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => date
                                                [value] => 20140102
                                                [label] => Date
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => browserType
                                                [value] => Chrome
                                                [label] => Browser Type
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [metric] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => visitDuration
                                                [value] => 1242
                                                [label] => Avg. Visit Duration
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => bounces
                                                [value] => 3
                                                [label] => Bounces
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => repeatVisitors
                                                [value] => 0
                                                [label] => Repeat Visitors
                                            )

                                    )

                                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => newVisitors
                                                [value] => 5
                                                [label] => New Visitors
                                            )

                                    )

                                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => visits
                                                [value] => 10
                                                [label] => Visits
                                            )

                                    )

                                [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [name] => pageViews
                                                [value] => 66
                                                [label] => Page Views
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )


            )       
    )
```

)

Above Xml array need to print like key and values type.The array showing like dimension and   metric.I want print the values inside @attributes nested array like key and value.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like xml, not json

Comment: [json_decode()](http://us2.php.net/json_decode)

Answer (score 1):

Found in the comments on php SimpleXml documentation:

```
function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{
foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
    $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

return $out;
}
```

Check the docs here: https://www.php.net/ref.simplexml